# Best way to render a round graphic on the web

Tags: css, svg, interface

Hej!

I'm using a simple dot in an animation for a graphic interface of a website - nothing fancy, but since round objects aren't very 'screenfriendly' I'm wondering;

Is a round div with

```
border-radius: 50%;
overflow: hidden;
background: #000;
```

or a round svg-graphic inside a square div rendered smoother? 
Is there even a (visual) different? 
If so when (and why)?

I'm just curious.

Thanks in advance, 
kind regards

Lucas

Comment: The best answer to this question is to try it yourself. Any answer will likely be dependent on your particular use case.

Comment: Alright then, I thought maybe there's a common ground on this. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you give the border a radius property, it **does not** make the `div` round. It simply makes the border round, but the `div` itself still remains a rectangle.

That being said, there should not be an issue with you using the `border-radius` property.

p.s. answers may vary, depending on what you are using the round `div` for.